# Get fid from file path

Tags: 7, theming, files

I've to create a custom function to display images because I've to add values from custom fields.

I've added a function to template php, like this:

```
function mytheme_image($variables) {  
}
```

The problem is that in $variables I haven't the fid of the file, but only the path. I have to load the file to get values from field, how should I do?

I'm looking for functions to get fid from path but I haven't found something..

Answer (score 5):

@pvorb, you can also use EntityFieldQuery.  See the first comment on https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_load_multiple/7 for an example.  Something along the lines of:

```
$filename = 'myfirstpony.png';
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'file')
  ->propertyCondition('filename', $filename)
  ->execute();
// if you are guaranteed there is exactly one result, then:
$file_object = reset($result['file']);
$fid = $file_object->fid;
// but beware you might get 0 or many results
```

If you have more information -- such as the path (from which you can generate a URI) -- then change the query condition to something like `->propertyCondition('uri', 'public://path/to/myfirstpony.png')`.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please remember: this is not a forum. Answer the question, not other answers or comments.

Comment: @molot, the original question was: "The problem is that in $variables I haven't the fid of the file, but only the path. I have to load the file to get values from field, how should I do?"

Comment: If you are addressing arrubiu's question, don't start your answer with "@pvorb, you can also" - that's misleading. If you are addressing pvorb's post, you shouldn't post it under arrubiu's question at all. Simple as that. You may comment @ someone else to tell him your answer solves their doubts, that's OK, but only answer to the question.

Comment: @molot, why are you being so pedantic?  pvorb asked on dman's answer how to answer arrubiu's original question but using EntityFieldQuery.  I did that.

Comment: @ElephantJim - I believe Molot is just trying to keep the q&a format clean and readable for future visitors. Sure no offence meant

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to change the image field output - you might want to look at the [theme_image_formatter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.field.inc/function/theme_image_formatter/7) function that you can override and add your variables to the $image var, that will be later sent to theme_image or theme_image_style.

Be aware, that theme_image is working with the paths, so it is possible that the function is not called from within the theme_image_formatter.

Comment: I've tried it, but using netbeans the system doesn't enter in the function while shows images.

Comment: so are the images coming through the image field and displayed as such?

Comment: Images are "file" field, with "media selector" as widget, and displayed as "rendered entity"

Answer (score 1):

Suggestions about formatting are helpful, but to answer the actual question, the answer at https://drupal.org/comment/6493610#comment-6493610 looks good.

```
// Take a look at: file.inc::file_load_multiple
$files = file_load_multiple(array(), array('uri' => $uri));
$file = reset($files); 
// If empty, $file will be false, otherwise will contain the required file
```

A two-liner instead of one, but should get the result we need.

Comment: `$conditions` is marked deprecated in `file_load_multiple()` so what to do instead?

Answer (score 1):

If using the *file_entity* module, you can use `file_uri_to_object` as it can load an existing file object (if exists) or create a new one.

http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!file_entity!file_entity.file_api.inc/function/file_uri_to_object/7

If not using this module, just copy this function from "Source" at the link above.

This is a core issue and should be fixed in D8 sometime: https://www.drupal.org/node/685818

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be the way to do it In Drupal 8

```
$files = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('file')->loadByProperties(['uri' => $uri]);
```

Where `$files` will be an array of file objects, keyed by the file id.