# How to give access to the files of node for individual users?

Tags: 7, users, media, files

In my website I have these modules enabled: [File Entity (fieldable files)](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_entity), [Media](https://www.drupal.org/project/media), [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference).

The default download method is: Private local files served by Drupal.

So when **userA** upload file to node. **userB** can't see it.

Q: How to give access to view file by entityreference(user) for **userB**?

---

**UPD:**

I create subdomain http://filesaccess.onenglar.com/

So you can login:

user: root

pass: root

---

**UPD2:**

Sharing access i think by entity reference field (user)

**But how share access to the files of node for individual users?))**

[image]

Comment: The questions is not cleaer, I suggest you to explain in more detail your exact current setup and what exactly you want to achieve.

Comment: @OnengLar: What do you mean by "***can't show it***"? Maybe you mean "***can't see it***"? If my guess is right, who or what is stopping userB to actually see it? Also, what do you mean by "***by entityreference(user) for userb***"? Maybe you mean "***userB is only allowed to see if there is a link to userB via some entityreference fiel***"? Sorry for being confused, but please try to edit your question to address these questions (to make them obsolete).

Comment: **userA** and **userB** are of the same role ? If yes it's kind of strange that they can't access files independently on who has uploaded them.

Comment: I tried your demo site. It seems both **test** and **test2** can't view the image.

Comment: I enabled **View private files** permission for authenticated user. All users can view the image now.

Comment: to @JimmyKo yep, but need share access only for some users, not for all

Comment: @OnengLar How do you specify the user who can view the image for a node? Or is it part of your question? You are better to update the question because it is not clear. Cheers.

Comment: Limiting files so that they are not visible to other users is not what the private file setting does.  I have lots of content types with private filesystem files attached to them that are visible even to anonymous users.  If I restricted access, then those users would no longer be able to see them because drupal does access checking before serving the file.  Access to those files is being prevented somewhere else.  As mentioned you could implement to hook_file_download() to explicitly allow access. I think the first thing you need to do is get to the bottom of why access is really restricted.

Comment: ... or maybe your question is just very unclear.  Are you saying that you would like to set things up so that access to the file is limited to the single user you selected in the give access to field?

Answer (score 4):

To do the access checking yourself you'll need to write a [`hook_file_download()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_file_download/7.x).

In broad strokes you'll need to get the actual file object (see [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50278/get-fid-from-file-path) for help with that), find the references with [`file_get_file_references()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!file!file.module/function/file_get_file_references/7.x), and finally load them to check each reference (probably just one but it would be unwise to assume that's true) to see if the current user is given access to the file.

Comment: Thanks!
q: You offer to work with the public system?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you're asking?  Will this solution work with a file in the public file system: probably not (Drupal isn't bootstrapped in that case)? Or do I do freelance work?

Comment: the first one..

Comment: Mostly: No, since your web server will serve that file directly without consulting Drupal. If you want control over file access when it is served you need to use private files (which is also slower). That said, you could still control when and how the page with a public file is rendered by using hook_node_view() or hook_node_view_alter() to change what's loaded and displayed, but the images themselves will still be accessible directly.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears to me that he just wants to show/print the picture only if the logged in user is the same as the entity reference user or is the node author.

Sorry I don't have time to write an explicit answer. Consider this an implicit or bare bones answer.

All you gotta do is create a template file for your content type.

Then in your template file with PHP use `Global User` to grab the current logged in User ID. Also, you will need to grab the User ID of the entity reference field, perhaps the raw value will have it? Use [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) to check that.

Almost forgot, you will also need the node author uid.

Once you have these 3 values, you do a simple check

```
if ($global_uid == $entity_reference_uid || $global_uid == $author_uid) {

print render($content['field_image']);  

}
```

If anyone wants to write a more explicit version of my answer, feel free.

Comment: Thanks!

Your solution good for public file system, but then, any user can access any files from url

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudocode (inasmuch as you'll need to do the work to get the CURRENT_USER_ID and ENTITY_REFERENCE_ID) that should work in a custom module:

```
function MYMODULE_file_download($uri) {
  # get CURRENT_USER_UID and ENTITY_REFERENCE_UID here
  if (!$CURRENT_USER_UID === $ENTITY_REFERENCE_UID) {
      return -1;
  }
  else {
      $info = image_get_info($uri);
      return array('Content-Type' => $info['mime_type']);
  }
}
```